# Ruby: How do you include a % sign in sprintf output?

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
sprintf("%02X" % 13)
```

Which outputs:

```
=>"OD"
```

I want my output to be:

```
=>"%0D"
```

I've tried:

```
sprintf("\%%02X" % 13)
```

but I get an error `warning: too many arguments for format string`. The same goes for:

```
sprintf("%%02X" %  13)
```

Is it possible to add a leading `%` in sprintf alone?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `Kernel#sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)? It is possible, of course, and it is explained there how.

Comment: Not sure where that warning comes from, I get `ArgumentError: too few arguments`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain in detail, what *precisely* is unclear to you in the documentation. That way, the Ruby developers have a chance to improve the documentation for future readers. Personally, I find "`%` | A percent sign itself will be displayed. No argument taken." pretty clear, but obviously you don't. It is likely that others see it the same as you, and so you can help them by helping the Ruby developers improve the documentation.

Answer (score 17):

A literal `%` has to be escaped as `%%`:

```
sprintf('%%') #=> "%"
```

Furthermore, you should either use [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) **or** [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-25), not both:

```
sprintf('%%%02X', 13)  #=> "%0D"
#               ^
#          comma here

'%%%02X' % 13          #=> "%0D"
#        ^
# percent sign here
```

If these are too many percent signs, you can separate the string literal to make it more obvious:

```
sprintf('%%' '%02X', 13)
#=> "%0D"
```

In Ruby, `'foo' 'bar'` is equivalent to `'foobar'`, i.e. adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated by the interpreter.

Comment: The question is trivial but this little insight was fun *"In Ruby, 'foo' 'bar' is equivalent to 'foobar', i.e. adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated by the interpreter."* I was completely unaware of that

Answer (score 5):

```
sprintf('%%%02X', 13)
  # => "%0D"
```

From [the ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

> Field: %  | Other Format: A percent sign itself will be displayed.  No argument taken.

i.e. You must escape the `%` character with a double `%%`; much like you much escape a single `\` with `\\` in regular strings.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use [`Integer#to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-to_s) :

```
"%" + 13.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0').upcase
#=> "%0D"
```

And since `%` has a [higher precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) than `+`, you could also write :

```
"%" + "%02X" % 13
#=> "%0D"
```

which is equivalent to

```
"%" + ("%02X" % 13)
#=> "%0D"
```

Comment: `13.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0').upcase.prepend('%')` is even longer ;-)